# Incorrect asp-action url on spa page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I am serving a spa from a specific controller in my ASP.Net core website. Let's call the controller `FooController`. The `Index` method returns the spa page. The spa page is wrapped inside the original `_Layout.cshtml` view, because it is content of a specific page of the website. The rest of the website is ASP.Net core.

In my _Layout.cshtml I have a link to the spa page:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Foo" asp-action="Index">Foo</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The relevant part of Startup.cs looks like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/foo"), builder =>
{
    builder.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "foo-spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" });
    });
});
```

Now, above works fine in a 'normal' flow. The asp-action link in my _Layout.cshtml is always generated as '/foo'. However, when I navigate to a subpage inside the spa, say '/foo/bar' and *refresh* the page, the asp-action link becomes '/foo%2fbar' instead of the expected '/foo'.

How can I make sure the link is always generated as '/foo' inside my _Layout.cshtml? Regardless of the subpage that is requested inside the spa?

Comment: Have you considered just putting `<a href="~/foo">`? Or using a `HtmlHelper`, like so: `<a href="@Url.Action( "Index", "Foo" )">`?

Comment: @Dai The Url.Action variant behaves the same as the question. I'm currently using `<a href="~/foo">` as a workaround.